# How I can join <div> with display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css, list, overflow, whitespace

I am developing a complex application and I need to use `div` for representing some information; **NO** `table`. My specific problem is when the box's information is organized, the content is separated.

This is my code:

```css
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#item1 {
  width: 500px;
}
#item2,
#item3 {
  width: 400px;
}
.item_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.item_li {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="overflow:scroll">
  <ul id="item_ul">
    <li id="item1" class="item_li">
      a
    </li>
    <li id="item2" class="item_li">
      b
    </li>
    <li id="item3" class="item_li">
      c
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would like transform my representation as in the next image:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `margin-left: 0;`. Or float all the `li` to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that you can do is:

1. Set `font-size: 0` for `item_ul` to remove the *space* characteristic of *inline* elements
2. Now reset the font-size to `initial` for the `item_li`

See demo below:

```css
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#item1 {
  width: 500px;
}
#item2,
#item3 {
  width: 400px;
}
#item_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-size: 0;
}
.item_li {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="overflow:scroll">
  <ul id="item_ul">
    <li id="item1" class="item_li">
      a
    </li>
    <li id="item2" class="item_li">
      b
    </li>
    <li id="item3" class="item_li">
      c
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Another option is to use `<!-- -->` in the markup (and yes you are right write all the `li` in a *single line*) - see demo below:

```css
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#item1 {
  width: 500px;
}
#item2,
#item3 {
  width: 400px;
}
#item_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.item_li {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="overflow:scroll">
  <ul id="item_ul">
    <li id="item1" class="item_li">
      a
    </li><!--
    --><li id="item2" class="item_li">
      b
    </li><!--
    --><li id="item3" class="item_li">
      c
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#item1 {
  width: 500px;
}
#item2,
#item3 {
  width: 400px;
}
.item_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.item_li_first {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.item_li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Question</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content" style="overflow:scroll">
    <ul class="item_ul">
      <li id="item1" class="item_li_first">
        a
      </li>
      <li id="item2" class="item_li">
        b
      </li>
      <li id="item3" class="item_li">
        c
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```