# Why does format change when I space out my <span>s?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this line of code with 5 different spans for different colors per letter

```html
<span style="color: #B03A2E;">A</span><span style="color: #76448A;">M</span><span style="color: #2874A6;">I</span><span style="color: #239B56;">T</span><span style="color: #B7950B;">Y</span>
```

However, I want my code to be organized better, so I "line breaked" the spans.

```html
<span style="color: #B03A2E;">A</span>
<span style="color: #76448A;">M</span>
<span style="color: #2874A6;">I</span>
<span style="color: #239B56;">T</span>
<span style="color: #B7950B;">Y</span>
```

The problem with doing this is that it leaves the HTML output spaced out instead of together as one word. Why is this, and can it be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can join <div> with display: inline-block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112239/how-i-can-join-div-with-display-inline-block)

Comment: `@kukkuz`, I'm seeing too many incorrect possible duplicates. I'm sure it's a duplicate of something else, though.

Comment: its the same thing - the space you see is a characteristic of *all* `inline` elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line Breaks and Multiple White Spaces are treated as a Single White Space in HTML, with some exceptions like `<pre>`. You want no White Spaces, then bunch 'em.

Answer (score 0):

first, try to not use inline styles in tags, its not a good practice. for your case, its better to do something like this :

HTML :

```
<span class="fontColor1 padding-right">A</span>
<span class="fontColor2 padding-right">M</span>
<span class="fontColor3 padding-right">I</span>
<span class="fontColor4 padding-right">T</span>
<span class="fontColor5 padding-right">Y</span>
```

css :

```
.fontColor1{color: #B03A2E;}
.fontColor2{color: #76448A;}
.fontColor3{color: #2874A6;}
.fontColor4{color: #239B56;}
.fontColor5{color: #B7950B;}
.padding-right{padding-right:5px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/8vfbebsr/1/

Comment: Padding right class add extra white space btween characters

Answer (score 0):

You should do this way:

```
<span style="color: #B03A2E;">A</span><!--
--><span style="color: #76448A;">M</span><!--
--><span style="color: #2874A6;">I</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
span {
   float: left;
}
```

```html
    <span style="color: #B03A2E;">A</span>
    <span style="color: #76448A;">M</span>
    <span style="color: #2874A6;">I</span>
    <span style="color: #239B56;">T</span>
    <span style="color: #B7950B;">Y</span>
```